# how to use __meta_kubernetes_node_label_<labelname>

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

I deployed node-exporter on kubernetes, and I want to use kubernetes_sd_config _*meta_kubernetes_node_label* to set labels for each node to distinguish servers of different teams, but how should this be used? I can't find the right solution

The node have label: team=backend

I write in https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/prometheus-operator/values.yaml

```yaml
    relabelings: 
      - sourceLabels: [__meta_kubernetes_node_label_team]
        separator: ;
        regex: ^(.*)$
        targetLabel: team
        replacement: $1
        action: replace
```

This does not take effect, the 'team=backend' not in the up{}

Comment: I'm facing the same want, as far as I can tell it's because `__meta_kubernetes_node_label_<labelname>` is part of the `node` type of `kubernetes_sd_config` and your scrape is probably an `endpoint` type: https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#endpoints